# How can convert DBObject value into long

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I want to convert `DBObject` value into long. I have value in db something like `id = 24100001000001`.

I'm using this code:

```
String totalcount = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM table";

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(totalcount, con);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

long count = (long)(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
```

Using this code, I'm getting an error:

> **System.InvalidCastException**: sSpecified cast is not valid.
>
> at Default.method1(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\aBhiShEkrANAa\Desktop\ABC\Prroject\Default.aspx.cs:line 43

I just want this id value into long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might contain `Null` values. So it would be better to use `Convert` instead of `cast` in this case, or even would be better to use something like this:

```
var temp = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
temp = (temp == DBNull.Value) ? null : temp;
long count = Convert.ToInt64(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Little bit simpler approach will be to use right type for the job:

```
var value = (long?)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

If you want to return default value instead of nullable:

```
var value = (long?)command.ExecuteScalar();
return value.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Nullable value will handle `DbNull` and using nullable will provide more information for other developers/readers.

Notice that actual value under `object` returned by `ExecuteScalar` is a long, using `Convert.ToInt64` will be much overhead, because converting do much more work.